# How to best implement the system of image loading in Android Studio

Tags: android

The bottom line is this. There is a list of users who need to download their images from the firebase storage.

[image]

Downloading of all images is not rational, because memory problems are unavoidable with a large number of users.

**The question: what should be done in this situation and realize this function most rationally?**

Comment: Did you read this? https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try image libraries [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Replace path with local folder path or server url

```
Glide.with (context).load (path).asBitmap().into(imageView);
```

These libraries will handle memory issue.